# Writing to http response stream while waiting on a Task to complete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm calling some long-running services and using Azure Relay to access them. The issue is Azure Relay requires a response within 60 seconds or I get a 504 timeout. I *do* want to have an actual timeout (2 min).

I'm attempting to solve this with 3 tasks by:

1. Starting a recursive task and sending data (`" "`) every 10 seconds
2. Using `WhenAny` with 2 tasks; my actual service call and `Task.Delay(120000)`
3. Wait until one of the tasks in step #2 completes and cancel the recursive #1 task.
4. If the completed task is my actual task, then return the results. Otherwise return 504 timeout.

When I test it with <10 seconds, things work fine. If I test it with > 10 seconds, I'm getting:

> `The HTTP status code, status description, and headers cannot be modified after writing to the output stream.`

I'm new to this and I think there are some fundamental things wrong with my code and that error is just a product of that.

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetNameAndDateTimeDelayKeepAlive")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetNameAndDateTimeDelayKeepAlive([FromQuery, DefaultValue(20)] int seconds)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var mainTask = _client.GetNameAndDateTimeDelayKeepAlive(seconds);

    // Start a recursive task that will send a " " every 10 seconds to the response stream
    var keepAliveTask = Task.Run(() => KeepAliveLoop(cts.Token));

    // Arbitrary 2 min MAX timeout
    var response = await Task.WhenAny(mainTask, Task.Delay(120000)).ConfigureAwait(true);

    // Cancel the keep alive loop
    cts.Cancel();

    // Task completed within the alloted timeout
    if (response == mainTask)
    {
        return Ok(mainTask.Result.response);
    }

    // If we're here then task didn't complete in 2 min timeout
    return new ObjectResult(this) { Value = "504 Gateway Timeout", StatusCode = 504 };
}

protected async Task KeepAliveLoop(CancellationToken ct)
{
    if (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Wait 10 seconds
        await Task.Delay(10000);

        // Write " " to the response stream to keep connection alive
        StreamWriter sw;
        await using ((sw = new StreamWriter(Response.Body)).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(" ").ConfigureAwait(false);
            await sw.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        // Call self to loop
        await KeepAliveLoop(ct);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't combine this kind of streaming with `ActionResult`.

`ActionResult` is a complete HTTP response, including status code, headers, and body. Streaming, though (i.e., writing to `Response.Body`) is done by writing the body. In order to write the body, the status code / headers must all already be sent.

So, as soon as your code starts writing to `Response.Body`, ASP.NET writes out the status code / headers. Then when your code returns `ActionResult`, it attempts to write out the status code, headers, and body; and you get the exception saying the status code / headers have already been written.

The only solution I know of is to not use `ActionResult` (or `Ok` or `ObjectResult`) in a method that writes to `Response.Body`. You'll have to do your own serialization of your response and write that to `Response.Body` instead.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is there a better way to keep a response open other than writing to the body then or am I stuck making my own thing? I was hoping I could do `Response.clear()`, but it doesn't seem to solve either.

Comment: @WilliamYK: Sounds like a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) may be a solution. Or WebSockets.

Comment: After reading your excellent blog it sounds like Azure Queue Storage could work for me with the returning the response the problem. I'm still reading up on Queue Storage, but if I take the request and immediately queue it, it looks like I get a "receipt" or something. Could I just return that, then the client could poll for that receipt. Then when I finally receive a response, could I put that in the queue as well to get popped off? Is that the concept of how it works?

Comment: Almost. The job statuses normally live in a db or something like that, rather than a queue.